# how to run BasicGenerator.scala in swagger

Tags: scala, code-generation, swagger

after running `./sbt assembly`, I'm trying to run the

```
./bin/runscala.sh src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/codegen/BasicPHPGenerator.scala  ~/Desktop/myspec.json
```

and I get the following error:

> ./src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/codegen/BasicPHPGenerator.scala:17: error: illegal start of definition
>
> package com.wordnik.swagger.codegen

What is the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could it be a byte order mark problem in your source file?

Comment: I didn't touch the source file, it is as it was cloned from [their repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd *strongly* recommend using the develop_2.0 branch of swagger-codegen which uses Java, is simpler, and is under active development. Please try it first and see if you still experience a problem.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/develop_2.0

Comment: You saved me a week of banging-head-against-the-wall

Comment: I have some failing tests, trying to `mvn package`, is it the same for everyone or do I have some wrong java/mvn configuration?

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on the repository with the error and we'll check it out. Please mention it's on the develop_2.0 branch.

Comment: to be honest, it's not working well for me. i've practically cloned every single repo from swagger and so far none of them have worked, except swagger-editor

Comment: I'd love to help further, but normally SO is not great for back-and-forth support but single Q&As. If you don't mind, please post to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket and I'll do my best to help with anything else. It also helps us in improving the docs.